# emacs-mozc doesn't work when coding-system is utf-8 in Ubuntu

Tags: emacs, utf-8

### My Problems

I use emacs24.4 in Ubuntu14.10. I installed emacs-mozc by *apt-get* command.
In order to enable it, I wrote following code in *.emacs.d/init.el*. 
It works as I expected.

**[.emacs.d/init.el]**

```
;; @mozc
(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
  (require 'mozc)
  (setq default-input-method "japanese-mozc")
  (set-language-environment "Japanese"))
```

Then I added following code because I want all files to be read or written as utf-8 encoding.
(Otherwise, emacs often fails to open utf-8 text.)

**[.emacs.d/init.el(cont'd)]**

```
;; setting coding-system
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

Unfortunately, when I type any japanese word and covert it, following error messages occurs in backtrace.

**[*Backtrace*]**

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "] in a list")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/yusuke/.kkcrc" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 930
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/yusuke/.kkcrc" "/home/yusuke/.kkcrc" nil nil)
  load("/home/yusuke/.kkcrc" nil nil t)
  load-file("/home/yusuke/.kkcrc")
  kkc-lookup-key(3 nil t)
  kkc-region(#<marker at 10536 in init.el> 10539)
  quail-japanese-kanji-kkc()
  call-interactively(quail-japanese-kanji-kkc)
  quail-start-conversion(97)
  quail-input-method(97)
```

### My questions

So, my question is as follows.

1. Does anyone know workaround for this emacs-mozc problem?

**or**

2. Does anyone know how to open utf-8 file properly in emacs without `(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)` and `(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)`

Related to question 2, I know that emacs recognizes coding system by adding following comment in each files. However it is not preferable for me.

```
-*- coding: utf-8; -*-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question No.1. Although I don't understand why, it works fine for me after I deleted `.kkcrc`, which exists home directory.